# Setting cookie on jsonify between two Flask applications?

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I have two separate Flask applications, one is an application that is purely an API and returns json. The other is the main app which will call the API application to do things, like authenticate.

Once authenticated, the API should return a jwt to the caller. I have `set_cookie()` that returns the jwt in a cookie, but this is not being set in the main application.

```
# api application for route /authenticate
def authenticate():
    response = jsonify({'test': 'test'})
    token = build_jwt()
    response.set_cookie('jwt', token)
    return response


# main application for route /helloworld
def helloworld():
    response = requests.get("https://.../authenticate")
    print request.cookies.get('jwt')   # <--- This is None
    print response.cookies             # <--- Exists here!

# for route /edit
def doEdit():
    verifyJWT(request.cookies.get('jwt')) # <--- currently fails because it's None
    # Do stuff if verified
```

Later, for a call that requires an authenticated user (ie, `doEdit()`), I have to check the jwt to see if it's valid. But since the cookie is not set in the main application in "/helloworld", do I have to explicitly set the cookie somehow after making that call to the api, so that I can later verify it in `doEdit()`?

Lastly, are there security issues to look out for in this setup, by doing this kind of jwt exchange through the cookies?

Comment: Cookies are stored by domain or subdomains, are you using the same for both apps?

Comment: Also, Flask uses the `secret key` value to sign your cookies, if you are using two differents Flask apps with two differents secret keys they won't be able to interchange the data.

Comment: @VMRuiz The secret key is the same for both applications. I think both apps will be under the same domain, but I'm just playing on my localhost for now (not using `https` yet, but will eventually).

Comment: I recommend to use Blueprint instead of two apps.